# KMeans algorithm in opencv

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv

i have some question about kmeans algorithm in opencv. I have a task to train neural network to recognize white spaces among letters and for training whitespaces i have a code like this `w_space_group = max(enumerate(k_means.cluster_centers_), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]` which should make clusters and separate letters from whitespace, and make groups of whitespaces.

Could someone explain me what means this `key=lambda x:x[1])[0]`? Also,what means `cluster_centers_`, is there some other property of k_means? Does k_means automatically know that his task is to separate letters from whitespaces? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enumerate` creates tuples of `(index, k_means.cluster_centers_[index])`. The `key` parameter tells the `max` function to use the second entry of that tuple for searching the maximum. (instead of using the index, which would not make much sense)

k-Means does not know that you want to separate whitespace from data. What it does is find k clusters in your data. So what the result means depends entirely on the input you present to k-Means.